# pavucontrol latency compensation greater than 99 ms

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio

When I connect my Bluetooth Headset to my notebook running ubuntu I notice a sound latency.
This is no big issue when I'm using a dedicated video player like vlc since I can compensate for it there.

But when I watch youtube videos (or any videos in my browser for that matter) I'd like to sync audio and video.
There seems to be an option in `pavucontrol` (output devices => bt headset => advanced options => latency) which seems to be able to do just that.
But the highest value I can input there is 99 ms which is just not enough.

Now I'm looking for a way to input a higher value preferably via that gui although I would be fine configuring it in config files manually as well.